# ExtJs multiple onReady execution

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs4.1

I am using mutliple Ext.onready functions on my page in the following way.

Page1.jsp has following structure -

```
<body>
<%@include file="/jsp/layout/page2.jsp" %>
<div id="restOfBodyContent">
<script type="text/javascript">
 Ext.onReady(function(){
     var obj=null;
    obj.split(':');//on this line error will be thrown

 });
</script>
</body>
```

Page2.jsp has following structure -

```
<body>
<div id="bodyContent">
<script type="text/javascript">
 Ext.onReady(function(){
    //some valid functionality
 });
</script>
</body>
```

When i execute above page then an error is thrown inside the Ext.onReady present on the page1 due to which Ext.onReady present on page2 is not executed.

Is there any way that I can ensure that Ext.onReady present inside the page2 is executed even though there is an error inside Ext.onReady of page1.

Thanks!

Comment: why not wrap with a try catch ?

Comment: What kind of error @4zh4r?

Comment: @procrastinator, that's what i have mentioned in my answer. if he knows its an error, it needs to be fixed. But having said that, it's up to the author to act upon.

Answer (score 0):

When you have an error in your script, i think you should go ahead and fix it, so that it works fine.

But in case you do not have control over that block of code or you want to skip that error, try to include it within a try catch, so that it doesn't affect the rest of the script.

```
Ext.onReady(function(){
    try {
        var obj=null;
        obj.split(':');//on this line error will be thrown
    } catch(e) { 
        console.log('error'); 
    }
});
```

Comment: If error is present then I am going to fix it or even I have an alternative of writing the method implementation inside try catch block. 

But I wanted to know whether there is a way where ExtJs provide some kind of config or mechanism to handle this kind of scenarios becuase even if try catch is not present then also we can ensure that other Ext.onReady methods are executed.